# Social collaboration in SharePoint

Tags: social, newsfeed

I am looking for a solution where people in my company can easily share short informatoin including images in Sharepoint. Basically I am looking for something sort of www.yammer.com like, but within the Shareppoint univers. It must be possible to do it from a mobile phone, be it blackberry, iPhone or other types of smartphones.

I've been over sending emails to a blog, and then show that in a webpart on my frontpage. I have also tried to find out, if the newsfeed from the mysite is the right solution, and even tried to find third party solutions. I haven't rueld out any of these solutions, but 
I have a feeling that a simple answer is right in fornt of my nose. I just can't seem to grasp it.

Anyone ells been in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just implement Yammer with SharePoint integration?  There are other customization or third party tools like NewsGator, but if that if you are specifically looking for yammer-like functionality, then just implement Yammer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything out of the box like that. The closest thing would be the Note Board, or you could make a custom Wall-type webpart fairly quickly but would need a bit more work for the mobile platforms.

But SharePoint is not that good at surfacing information. What's wrong with Yammer? The free version would already give you what you want. NewsGator is very similar to Yammer but is a (paid) on premises installation.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with Yammer:) the only thing is, that I would like to embed it in SharePoint. I think there are some options for that

Comment: Yes, there's an extensive API even in the free version. You can easily embed a thread in any page.

Answer (score 0):

The 'My Site' feature in SharePoint 2010 provides the basis of enterprise social computing ("FaceBook of the SharePoint Enterprise"). The following posts (using OOTB) may be of help in getting you started -

[My Sites overview (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382643.aspx)

[SharePoint 2010 MySite in detail](http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-mysite-in-detail.html)

[Manage My Sites settings (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656740.aspx)

[SharePoint 2010 My Sites (a nice series)](http://weshackett.com/2011/01/sp2010-mysites-part-one-overview/)

[UPDATE] - From a leading business journal FORBES:

[FINALLY, Microsoft Embraces Social -- And It's Going to be Big](http://www.forbes.com/sites/markfidelman/2012/03/13/finally-microsoft-embraces-social-and-its-going-to-be-big/)

There is a 'Content By Query Web Part' that can be customized to show query results from different sources. Here's a post on ['How to: Customize RSS for the SharePoint Content By Query Web Part'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608445.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I will look into those, but perhaps you wou know the answer to one simple question:

Comment: which is this:Is it possible to Display the newsfeed from mysite on, say, the sharepoint default page? I am interested in picking up all newsfeeds in one place. It should be dependent on who I have chosen as a colleague. I have seached and searched, but havent been able to come up with an answer.

Comment: @Kathrine - I have updated my answer above with a post that has an example of customized 'Query Web Part' that can work with RSS feeds